# Antd Tooltip on an image useMap reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, image, imagemap

Why is my ANTD tooltip position is always fix on a straight line no matter how i change the style of the tooltips? Here's the link for the problem stated:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-image-v9q3t?file=/index.js

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding `style = {{ position: "absolute" ...... }}` into each div of the Tooltip solved my problem!